# Website forward in .htaccess not forwaring

Tags: .htaccess, forward

Having an issue with my .htaccess file. I'm trying to get it to forward from site1.com to site2.com (on another host) so in the .htaccess file for site2, I added this code in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site1\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.site1\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/site2\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This looks like the sort of code that cPanel generates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put those rules in the htaccess file in the document root for **site1**, not site 2. Otherwise, those rules won't do anything because if someone goes to site1, the apache server doesn't have any rules to redirect.